# Excel VBA - How to convert an Object into a String

Tags: excel, vba, casting, typeconverter

I like to convert an Object into a string. I found this [topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78797/representing-objects-as-strings-in-vba) but I can not get it to work in Excel 2010 ("Cast.xxx", "CArray()" and "Array()" seems to be unknown to Excel?)

I know how to convert a variant e.g. "toString = CStr(x)"  but not how to do it the best way for an object

```
Function toString(ByVal x As Variant) As String
  If TypeOf x Is Object  Then
      toString = ???   
  Else
      toString = CStr(x)
  End If
End Function
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for my Ignorance. Isn't CStr working for the Object also. I tried a bit like that where my object was converted to string. So asking this question

Comment: No in some cases you will get an excpetion back e.g. in case the type is a "Collection" or "Dictionary", so I hoped that some experts here may have written some scripts which converts most of the used types in Excel

Comment: Do you intend to list object's properties and methods only? Then you can retrieve them by JS code like `for (var oItem in oSample) {oDict.Add(oItem, oSample[oItem]);}` executed within `ScriptControl`. Or if you transform the string into the object back later, take a look at [Serialization/Deserialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and [Marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science))/[Unmarshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmarshalling). AFAIK VBA has no native implementation of them. Anyway the solution depends on the objects types.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the IFormattable interface. For example in VB.NET?

Excel VBA isn't a language that will provide you with a ToString method since it doesn't support inheritance.

In your example, you are simply converting whatever the variant is to a string, but an object in VBA wont support this directly.

If you have an external COM object, this would need to be exposed in the interface to access this method to call it from VBA.

For your own classes, you could implement your own IFormattable interface for your objects, but you would have assign to that interface before being able to call the objects ToString method - possible with a helper method. You could of course just supply a ToString method for every class which will through the class interface, but if you want to include this functionality for all objects, then an interface is probably the way to go.

Hope that helps.